# Recreating viewpages

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have three pages in the ViewPager and what I am trying to achieve is that when I swipe and a new page gets selected, the pages will be recreated with new variables values.

- Page 0 shows value 0
- Page 1 shows value 1
- Page 2 shows value 2

When I swipe to the next page I want the following pages:

- Page 0 showing value 1
- Page 1 showing value 2
- Page 2 showing value 3

What happens now  is that when I swipe once it will print out arg0 in a loop with increments of 3.

Initial values:

```
private int zero = 0;
private int one = 1;
private int two = 2;
```

createViews method:

```
public void createViews(){
    FrameLayout v0 = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_schema, null);
    TextView t = (TextView) v0.findViewById(R.id.test);
    t.setText("" + zero);
    FrameLayout v1 = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_schema, null);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.test);
    t1.setText("" + one);
    FrameLayout v2 = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_schema, null);
    TextView t2 = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.test);
    t2.setText("" + two);
    pagerAdapter.addView(v0, 0);
    pagerAdapter.addView(v1, 1);
    pagerAdapter.addView(v2, 2);
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

onPageSelected method:

```
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
System.out.println(arg0);
    if(arg0==0){
        zero--;
        one--;
        two--;
    }else if(arg0==2){
        zero++;
        one++;
        two++;
    }
    createViews(); 
}
```